# Where can I find old .vb form width and height?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, projects-and-solutions

I have some old vb.net forms (can't find out which version they were using when they made them), and I can't find the form's Width and Height in any of the files.

The forms don't have a .designer.vb file, and it's not in the .vb "Windows Form Designer generated code" section either. However, when I open the form in the design view, I can see the values perfectly in the Properties tab.

I've tried making a file search for the values independently but there are nowhere to be found.

Any suggestions or ideas?

I have googled for some time but I can't find anything that helps.

Comment: Are they maybe default values?

Comment: Checked for a `Size` property too?

Comment: Just from testing in a new VB6 project, you can see the ClientWidth and ClientHeight values if you open the form in notepad.  It won't be the same value as when you have the project open though.  i.e., I have the height of my form set at 3600, but the frm file shows ClientHeight = 3030.  Or if I set the Height to 2400 the ClientHeight becomes 1830.  So maybe that's why you can't search for your value?

Comment: @Pikoh knowing what the values are, it's highly improbable. Also, Visual Studio marks them in Bold, which means they have been set up by the original creator of the form.

Comment: @AFriend yes. I did that too and didn't find anything.

Comment: @Capellan it's vb.net, not .VB6, and I already checked in notepad++ the file itself. There are no size references, although I'm going to check a bit about the different scales thing, just in case.

Comment: Create a new form, put it over said form, size it... and get the height/width? Stupid suggestion I know but...

Comment: @TonyW, that won't work. The problem is with OLD vb.net forms. New vb.net forms create a .designer.vb file where you can find (and manipulate) everything.

Comment: I know, I meant.... literally pull up the old form (That you don't know the size of)... Create a new form in a new project while the old form is on the screen, and put the new form literally over the old form, size it.... and you can get an approximate, rather than having ZERO idea.

Comment: The Width and Height (or Size) properties are not stored, they don't repeat well from one machine to another.  Only the ClientSize is stored.

Comment: @TonyW can't do that. The form is too big to make it from scratch and the risk of not doing it perfectly right is too high at this moment.

Comment: @HansPassant what do you mean they are not stored? I mean, they must be somewhere. I doubt Visual Studio gets them "magically".

I'm starting to think that those values are a consequence of the controls the form has inside, and are calculated each time you open the form in the design view.

Comment: Well, as last resort you can always google for any free file monitoring application (eg. http://www.moo0.com/software/FileMonitor/ ) and determine which file is read/wrote when you do changes on the Form.Size property at design-time in the property grid of the Form. --- Otra opción sería compartir por privado el proyecto y yo intentaría analizar el problema.

Comment: @ElektroStudios the thing is that when I change the values it does save them in the .vb file. The current values are the one that are a mistery to me.

--- Eso sí, no te lo puedo compartir por temas de privacidad varios. Es el proyecto troncal de mi empresa y estaría infringiendo como 3 o 4 acuerdos.

Comment: The Control class (from which Form class inherits) exposes a **DefaultSize** property, maybe the reason why you are not seeying the current size value of the Form could be because the size value was never set/serialized and it is using the base Form.DefaultSize value instead?.

Comment: @ElektroStudios I'm quite sure it's not a default value. The numbers are too high and too... "odd".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests, I'm quite sure the value comes from the sizes of everything else it has inside.

The form has various Group controls that "force" the Form's size, and therefore, there's no need to stablish it manually. If I do so, the values appear as usual, but otherwise, they are not stored anywhere.